# Can be ping-ed but failed to SSH (Might be server hangs)

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, hang

We have a server that can be ping-ed but failed to SSH.

Here's the verbose of ssh

```
[user@/etc]$ssh -v user@111.111.111.111
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 111.111.111.111 [111.111.111.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /hey/hey2/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /hey/hey2/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /hey/hey2/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /hey/hey2/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /hey/hey2/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /hey/hey2/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
```

Per the above output, it seems like it hangs so I just have to `ctrl + c` just to close the ssh command.

There is no failure of SSH, its just like hangs.

We suspect that the server hangs.

**NOTE**: Changed the IP for security purposes.

Answer (score 4):

If you remote server has a DNS Server configured (check in `/etc/resolv.conf`) the SSH Server will try to do a reverse DNS lookup of the client's IP address. If it's not resolvable, it will wait for a 30s timeout to give you access. So it may be not hanging.

Also check if you can ssh from within the server (through the `127.0.0.1` local IP) to check if it properly working. an `sshd -t` may also help troubelshoot any syntax check on the `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`.

Comment: OpenSSH stopped performing reverse DNS lookups by default as of release 6.8 ([march 2015](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html)). The functionality can still be enabled with `UseDNS yes` in `sshd_config`, if the server admin so desires.